# How can I get special web elements in appending function with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with this, when I have a bottom function to appending some web elements, like this:

```
 var index = 0;
    $("#addGift").click(function () {
        var gift = "<ul id=\"ul\">\n" +
            "        <li>\n" +
            "            <label>Gift Type1</label>\n" +
            "            <select name=\"giftType\">\n" +
            "                <option value=\"coin\">coin</option>\n" +
            "                <option value=\"album\">album</option>\n" +
            "                <option value=\"vip\">vip</option>\n" +
            "            </select>\n" +
            "        </li>\n" +
            "        <li>\n" +
            "            <label>Num</label>\n" +
            "            <input type=\"number\" name=\"num\">\n" +
            "        </li>\n" +
            "        <li>\n" +
            "            <label>Time</label>\n" +
            "            <input name=\"time\" class=\"easyui-datebox\" data- 
     options=\"sharedCalendar:'#cc'\">\n" +
            "        </li>\n" +
            "        <li>\n" +
            "            <label>Unit</label>\n" +
            "            <select name=\"unit\">\n" +
            "                <option value=\"day\">day</option>\n" +
            "                <option value=\"month\">month</option>\n" +
            "            </select>\n" +
            "        </li>\n" +
            "        <li>\n" +
            "            <label>Gift Type2</label>\n" +
            "            <select name=\"giftType\">\n" +
            "                <option value=\"coin\">coin</option>\n" +
            "                <option value=\"album\">album</option>\n" +
            "                <option value=\"vip\">vip</option>\n" +
            "            </select>\n" +
            "        </li>\n" +
            "        <li>\n" +
            "            <label>Num</label>\n" +
            "            <input type=\"number\" name=\"num\">\n" +
            "        </li>\n" +
            "        <li>\n" +
            "            <label>Time</label>\n" +
            "            <input name=\"time\" class=\"easyui-datebox\" data- 
    options=\"sharedCalendar:'#cc'\">\n" +
            "        </li>\n" +
            "        <li>\n" +
            "            <label>Unit</label>\n" +
            "            <select name=\"unit\">\n" +
            "                <option value=\"day\">day</option>\n" +
            "                <option value=\"month\">month</option>\n" +
            "            </select>\n" +
            "        </li>\n" +
            "    </ul>"
        $("#giftTable").append(gift);
        index++;
    });
```

I had try many ways to get that web elements like `name='time'` or `name='unit'`  to do show or hide action, but it doesn't work. Because I didn't get that elements correctly.

So how can I get special web elements in appending function with  Jquery?

Comment: What do you mean "do show or hide"?

Comment: Also you're potentially repeating an id on the top `ul` if this method is called multiple times, which is invalid markup by web standards

Comment: If you need to get a reference to those new elements you need to do it after creating/adding them

Comment: As a side note: if you have that amount of html it might be more beneficial to have it in a separate file and load it when needed, or store it in a hidden element like `<script type="template">` and grab it from there. And new lines \n in html aren't really useful since they are collapse to being a non-breaking space

Comment: You need to select the elements only after you have appended the element to the DOM (which is after `.append` call). And you seriously need to separate out your html and javascript. (simple way)Create `ul` in html, hide it, append it in javascript when needed.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I was writting the same thing. :)

Comment: They may not need to get the reference after they are created, depending on what "do show or hide" means.  Potentially this is a delegate event handler situation, but the OP has not replied back with more information yet to make this apparent.

Comment: Welcome to SO. On a side note, my recommendation is to create all those HTML in a div and hide it and when it's time to append, just show it. It's easier to edit and maintain.

Comment: I will write a new question in it because I wrote this one is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow.

ECMAScript 6 (ES6) introduces a new type of literal, namely **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**. They have many features, variable interpolation among others, but most importantly for this question, they can be multiline.

A template literal is delimited by *backticks*:

```
var index = 0;
$("#addGift").click(function () {
    var gift = `<ul id="ul">
                  <li>
                    <label>Gift Type1</label>
                    <select name="giftType">
                        <option value="coin">coin</option>
                        <option value="album">album</option>
                        <option value="vip">vip</option>
                    </select>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>Num</label>
                    <input type="number" name="num">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>Time</label>
                    <input name="time" class="easyui-datebox" data-options="sharedCalendar:'#cc'">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>Unit</label>
                    <select name="unit">
                        <option value="day">day</option>
                        <option value="month">month</option>
                    </select>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>Gift Type2</label>
                    <select name="giftType">
                        <option value="coin">coin</option>
                        <option value="album">album</option>
                        <option value="vip">vip</option>
                    </select>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>Num</label>
                    <input type="number" name="num">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>Time</label>
                    <input name="time" class="easyui-datebox" data-options="sharedCalendar:'#cc'">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>Unit</label>
                    <select name="unit">
                        <option value="day">day</option>
                        <option value="month">month</option>
                    </select>
                   </li>
                </ul>`;

    $("#giftTable").append(gift);
    index++;
});
```